# Citrix redrawing problems in kubuntu 21.10

Tags: kubuntu, citrix

Since upgrading from kubuntu 20.10 (via 21.04) to 21.10, my citrix session to my work (Windows) has become pretty much unusable, with windows not being redrawn properly:
[screenshot of citrix session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4svpp.png).

I am pretty sure it is not an issue with citrix itself: this system has worked for I think 5 years, and became unusable after the upgrade, 2 weeks ago. I have always used a manually-installed version of Citrix Reciever, which was not upgraded.

```
tijmen@Betsy:~/Programs/Connexxion VPN$ ./ICAClient/wfica -version
Citrix Receiver for Linux
Version 13.2.0.322243
```

Since having these issues I tried a new way of logging in to Citrix, now no longer via VPN+Citrix Reciever, but Netscaler+Citrix Workspace, which looks like a newer version of the Citrix Reciever launched from the browser (without the need for a VPN session) and installed from [the Citrix download page](https://www.citrix.com/nl-nl/downloads/workspace-app/linux/workspace-app-for-linux-latest.html):

```
tijmen@Betsy:/opt/Citrix/ICAClient$ ps -ax | grep ica
   7717 ?        Sl     0:26 /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfica -icaroot /opt/Citrix/ICAClient /tmp/mozilla_tijmen0/Q29udHJvbGxlci5LQSBEZXNrdG9wIDIwMTY-.ica
tijmen@Betsy:~$ /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/wfica -version
Citrix Workspace for Linux
Version  21.12.0.18 
Copyright 1998-2021 Citrix Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.
Copyright (c) 1986-1997 RSA Security, Inc. All rights reserved.
```

This has exactly the same problems, whether running in full screen or in a windowed mode.

I really have no idea where to begin to look for a solution, as window managers is not at all my forte - I have always used just what kubuntu supplied. I apparently use Wayland and X.Org 1.20.13. I have Intel graphics (Intel Core i7-6700 with built-in graphics card). No hardware was changed in the upgrade.

As I am at loss as to where the problem might lie, searches for people with similar problems have not been fruitful, and no sign of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Xorg and not Wayland? From your message it is not clear.

For me this is a workaround an issue with Citrix and Ubuntu 22.10. Fullscreen across 2 monitors does not work well any longer.

But are you sure the Citrix version you use is the same as when it last worked?

Comment: I was using Xorg.
I have updated ubuntu to 23.04, re-installed icaclient, now it works.
Thanks for helping though!